# trying to get category name instead of its ID

Tags: wordpress

`$args = array( 
        'numberposts' => 6,
        'category' => '233',
);`

instead of the ID "233", I want to be able to add the name of that category
how can I do that ?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `category_name` parameter.

Replace:

```
'category' => 233,
```

With:

```
'category_name' => 'ENTER-SLUG-HERE'
```

Make sure you use the category slug and not the title. Also in your question you have single quotes around your category ID which is invalid (plus it should be `cat`, not `category`). You should have been entering an integer rather than a string.

Further reading: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

Comment: the "Category Parameters" link u provided was very helpful thanks againe